# how to upload image in correct path - image: Property "image" expects a valid pathname as data in akeneo

Tags: path, cpanel, import-from-excel, akeneo

[image]
i already installed akeneo 2.0

I need to upload an image via Xl file

but I give the path
showing

> Warning
>
> image: Property "image" expects a valid pathname as data, "/tmp/pim/upload_tmp_dir/01.png" given.

how I can solve this???

Answer (score 3):

In order to import images while import products, you will have to include it in your zip archive, and use its relative path (compared to your product import file) in the archive.
e.g if your archive file has the following structure:

```
- products_import.xlsx
- images/
      image1.png
```

you will have to put `./images/image1.png` in the `image` column of your products_import.xlsx file

Then upload the zip archive (instead of only the Excel file) in the import profile: [image]

Comment: where to i upload all images   (path)

Comment: you have to import the whole zip file, I edited my answer to make it clearer